# Should Corda Workflow be used to manage general business workflow

Tags: corda

I am writing Corda App for financial transactions between companies. The incoming transaction initiates a business workflow at the receiving end. Can Corda flows be used as a general purpose BPMN software or is it a better design to use a separate BPMN software and trigger flow in that system?

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the kind of BPMN you have in mind.

However, within a flow you have full access to any JVM libraries. You can perform networking (see the Flow HTTP sample [here](https://github.com/corda/samples)), DB reads (see the Flow DB sample [here](https://github.com/corda/samples)), and anything else.